# Asp.net Core Authentication

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core

When I add the following code in startup.cs:

```
services.AddMvc(x =>
        {
            var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder().RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build();
            x.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
        }).AddXmlSerializerFormatters();
```

It gives me following error.

HTTP Error 404.15 - Not Found
The request filtering module is configured to deny a request where the query string is too long.

Image is attached:
[Error I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iwnk2.png)

Comment: Looks like you are requiring authentication globally and have not added an exception to the login page with `[AllowAnonymous]`. It is causing an infinite loop.

Comment: @juunas exactly that's the error. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging by the URL, you are caught in an infinite loop.

In this case the reason is probably that since you are requiring authentication globally, the user is denied access to the login page.
Be sure to exclude such actions/pages from the authentication requirement with `[AllowAnonymous]`.